# SwiftUI "No arguments" Error when using website links

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, storyboard

I'm developing a simple contacts application, when adding the lines shown below, I receive the error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments.

```
let websitetext: String
init(){
    self.websitetext = contact.website
}
```

Below is the entire file with irrelevant data removed.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContactsDetailView: View{
    let contact: Contact
    let websitetext: String //lines referenced
    init(){
        self.websitetext = contact.website
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            VStack {
                Image(contact.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(50)
            
                Text(contact.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 21, weight:.medium, design: .default))
                Form{
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Phone")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(contact.phone)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.callout)
                    }
                    Section{
                        Link("Website", destination: URL(string:  websitetext)!) //Uses the website text variable
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ResourcesDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactsDetailView(contact: contacts[0]) //ERROR LINE
    }
}
```

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: You have added a custom init which means the init you are using for your preview is no longer being generated by the compiler so it doesn't exist anymore. Besides that you must have some arguments in your init so you can set the `let` declared properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so would it be a better idea to remove the init and consider doing this another way? I'm fairly new to swift and just really want to get this link to work. I didn't expect it to be this hard haha

Comment: Either create an init that takes Contact as an argument, `init(contact: Contact)`, or since the property `websitetext` seems redundant (you can use `contact.website` instead) delete it and the current init so you only have the init that the compiler then generates for you.